Apache Flink Application Autoscaling Issue
I have an Apache Flink application deployed using the Flink Kubernetes Operator on AWS EKS. The application operates smoothly without autoscaling. However, after enabling autoscaling, I’ve noticed that some JobManager pods are being unpredictably terminated, while new pods are provisioned.
Below is the configuration I’ve used to enable autoscaling:
# AUTO SCALING CONFIGURATIONS
job.autoscaler.enabled: "true"
job.autoscaler.scaling.enabled : "true"
job.autoscaler.stabilization.interval: 10m
job.autoscaler.metrics.window: 10m
job.autoscaler.target.utilization: "0.5"
job.autoscaler.target.utilization.boundary: "0.1"
job.autoscaler.restart.time: 5m
job.autoscaler.catch-up.duration: 10m
job.autoscaler.restart.time-tracking.enabled: "true"
jobmanager.scheduler: "adaptive"

#AUTO TUNING CONFIGURATIONS
job.autoscaler.memory.tuning.enabled: "true"
job.autoscaler.memory.tuning.maximize-managed-memory: "true"
job.autoscaler.memory.tuning.overhead: "0.2"

I’ve reviewed the JobManager logs but haven’t found any relevant errors. I also checked the kubectl events, but they only indicate that the terminating pods are being shut down without providing details on the cause.
We are intermittently encountering this error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Target file s3://checkpoints/37a85e75d27358fc17f1f95e747bf70b/chk-16/_metadata already exists.

Apache Flink version: 1.19 
Flink Kubernetes Operator version: 1.9
Could anyone assist in diagnosing the root cause of this issue and suggest a possible solution?

Can you try disabling adaptive scheduling? I've run into an issue like this in the past where scaling events would result in stateful errors like these and disabling that eventually fixed it. Also do you have high availability enabled for the job and can you verify that the target/expected file exists?
